# java StdDraw formula for ratio

Tags: java, std

Say I two intervals; first between 1.23483 and 1.23595
and the second between 20 and 80.

Now if I have a value on the first interval, how would I get the value on the second interval that has the same ratio?
[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather appears to be a very basic math question.

Comment: You are looking something called mapping

Comment: Mapping? It looks like floating point division to me.

Comment: I'm of course not expecting the formula to be included in stdlib, that's just what I'm working with. The formula can be anything really as long as it does what I need.

Comment: Mapping seems to be what I need. Thank you. I just needed someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Lommmp Good to know that it helped you